# T-SQL to deploy a DACPAC from a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dacpac

Right now on each server instance I have an admin database with a stored procedure `CreateClientDB` which creates an empty database whenever a new client signs up, then calls a series of elaborate scripts to create the tables, views, functions, stored procedures, load reference data, etc. for that new client database.

I consider this approach to be pretty 'old school' and would like to deploy a data-tier application using a template DACPAC for each new client when needed, so both the deployments and upgrades are correctly managed & versioned.

What is the best way from a stored procedure to deploy a DACPAC file? Microsoft Docs discusses using `SQLPackage.exe`, or using the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac` assembly in PowerShell or in .NET code.

What would be the most reliable & portable across servers way to do this in a stored procedure?

Comment: This is not an appropriate task for a stored procedure. You should rearchitect things so the provisioning happens through external code.

Comment: I''m not surprised by your comment, Martin. Unfortunately, this process of creating new client databases via a Stored Procedure call is already in place, and I'm tasked with providing some updates. So I'm trying to figure out if using DACPAC deployments will avoid the foreseeable updating headaches, etc.

Comment: I doubt it. I just forsee it causing more headaches. You could try creating a SQL CLR stored procedure with external access  but that already limits portability and I've no idea whether the dacpac assemblies and utilities are even part of the standard Sql server install and you can assume that they will be on the server.

Comment: Martin, CreateClientDB is being called by an SSIS package right now.  I guess one way to re-architect this would be to write custom Task in SSIS to use the Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac assembly to deploy the DACPAC file for a New client, and just have an Administrator run a Powershell when Updates are needed.

Comment: Yes definitely doing it in SSIS would be much better than trying to do it from inside the database. SQL Agent does also support power shell script tasks and you can run a job from a stored procedure which may or may not be useful.

Comment: OK, that sounds good. Do you want to answer the question with: move it to either SSIS custom Task or Powershell called from SQL Agent, and then I'll mark your answer as Accepted?